# QML model link to JSON data

Tags: json, qml

How to link a JSON stream to a QML model like you would do with angularJS?

In  my QML, I have a Websocket object that receives data from a server:

```
WebSocket {
  id: socket
  url: "ws://3.249.251.32:8080/jitu"
  onTextMessageReceived: { var jsonObject = JSON.parse(message) }
  onStatusChanged: 
    if (socket.status == WebSocket.Error) { console.log("Error: " + socket.errorString) } 
    else if (socket.status == WebSocket.Open) { console.log("Socket open"); } 
    else if (socket.status == WebSocket.Closed) { console.log("Socket closed"); }
  active: false
}
```

In this JSON I have something like:

```
{ items: [ "FOO", "BAR" ] }
```

Then I want to display two tabs, on titles FOO and the other, unsurprisingly, titled BAR.

This work great if I create a repeater that goes through the array in my model and create a tab for each entry:

```
TabView {
  anchors.fill: parent
  Repeater {
    model: ListModel { id: tabs }
    Tab {
      title: Caption
      Rectangle { color: "red" }
    }
  }
}
```

Up to now, this really looks like angularJs. I just need now to update my model (scope for angular) with the data received through the websocket.
For this, I have to add the tabs from my JSON to the ListModel as such:

```
...
  onTextMessageReceived: { 
    var jsonObject = JSON.parse(message)
    tabs.append(jsonObject.ITU.Modalities);
  }
...
```

The problem is, each time I'll receive an update from JSON, tabs will be added. I don't want to clear the ListView each time, that would be time consuming I think. Is there a smart way to update the model from JSON smartly ? In angular, as they are both javascript structure, they are easy to merge. But here, I don't see an easy way.

Comment: I am not sure if it is easier way and if it's possible with WebSocket component, but you could keep track of in which state your application and server is. Therefore you will have to write some api to your server to send only data that is missing, not full json. Then probably you would have to set up some databases, and I think that is far too much work. If your json is not that big, then keep it simple.

Comment: Yes, let the server publish only the necessary update and not the whole JSON. It will also reduce bandwidth usage. I'll look into that.